# How to access a json object inside another json object inside another object?

Tags: javascript, json

So I basically I have a json object that inside of it has a json object called "from". Then from has a json object inside of it called value, then inside of value is address. I am trying to access address here:

```
        let data = doc.data();
                const email = JSON.parse(data.Emails[z]);

                let emailBody = email.body;
                let emailSubject = email.subject;
                let oldDate = email.date;
                let emailFrom = email.from.value.address;
```

in the emailFrom variable. I thought email.from.value.address would do the trick but it does not seem to be working.

currently email.from allows me to access the from object but I am trying to figure out how to access value and then address as well with it. Here is an example of the from json object as well

```
,"from":{"value":[{"address":"admin@removed","name":"World Cafe"}],"html":"<span class=\"mp_address_group\"><span class=\"mp_address_name\">W World Cafe</span> &lt;<a href=\"mailto:admin@removed.com\" class=\"mp_address_email\">admin@removed</a>&gt;</span>","text":"World Cafe <admin@removed.com>"}}"
```

hoping someone can point me in the right direction here, thanks so much =]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like

```
email.from.value[0].address
```

As value is `array` you have to specify index.

Comment: I was so close haha! Thanks so much buddy =] Ill accept answer in 10 when it lets me it worked perfect

Answer (score 1):

you need to do something like this email.from.value[0].address
as you are storing an array in value.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In your json object, the type of property `email.from.value` is `array` and array values can be accessed by its index.
Try this:

```
let emailFrom = email.from.value[0].address;
```

Comment: Well explained. Would remove `(object)` because it's confusing near `array`.